# Nativescript Socketio extraHeaders are lost

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, cors, nativescript

I try to authenticate my users through my socketio v4 nativescript - nodejs

## Setup

```
"@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
"@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio": "^5.0.0",
"nativescript-angular": "~8.21.0",
```

#### Client side

I wrote this app.module.ts

```
SocketIOModule.forRoot('http://10.0.2.2:3000', {
  debug: true,
  log: true,
  extraHeaders: {
    'authorization': `Bearer ${getString('ACCESS_TOKEN')}`
  },
}),
```

And simply `this.socketIO.connect();`

## Problem

The problem is that my server does not receive my extraheaders at all. I can't authenticate properly.

## My research

Using Chrome Dev Tool to debug, my websocket requests are not logged at all.
[Chrome Dev Tools](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/606457628729671691/846010994983305256/unknown.png)

By adding `console.log('url', args);` at line 73 of index.android.js (nativescript-socketio lib).
Above `this.socket = io.socket.client.IO.socket(args[0], opts.build());`
The headers are correctly present

By inspecting what the server receives.

```
{
  accept: '*/*',
  host: '10.0.2.2:3000',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'user-agent': 'okhttp/3.12.12'
}
```

With another tools : [SocketIO Online Client Tool](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/)
The server receives the headers correctly

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',     
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIU............V4MKGQ',
  origin: 'https://amritb.github.io',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-gpc': '1'
}
```

Finally, I thought it was a CORS problem (which I think is unlikely because there are no errors). My server socket uses the following options. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/)

```
{
  cors: {
      origin: '*',
      allowedHeaders: ['authorization']
    }
  }
}
```

I have found similar issues, but their solution doesn't change anything.

Has anyone ever faced this problem? Do you have any other ideas? I am out of ideas.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

Did you try, if it only affects the Authorization header?

And can you try to use `withCredentials` = `true`

Comment: I tested with another header `"test": "test"` and also does not appear on the server side. There is no "withCredentials" options with the nativescript-socketio lib, I tried with `"secure": true` and it still doesn't work